# Azure Cloud Template Missing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, cloud, project-template

After running the command `devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates` (as detailed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241279.aspx)), the Azure Cloud Template remains missing.

I'm running VS2010 Ultimate SP1 and install afterwards Azure SDK using WPI. I restarted my machine but it's still missing. The link below is the screenshot of the missing cloud template including the installed programs in my machine.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try manual install of Windows Azure tools for Visual Studio 2010 (WindowsAzureTools.VS100.exe) tools form
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=28045